# compressing code with C# generics

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the following 2 methods that i thing could be compressed in one method using generics. What i have tried can not compile. Can someone let me know how this can be done? I need to check that 2 differents field of the table AgeLengths have at least one values. 
Str_table  has one to many relationship with AgeLengths.

```
public static bool HasMeanWeight(int id)
{
    MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext ();
    return  (from s in dc.Str_table 
             where s.SId == id 
             select s.AgeLengths
             .Where(a => a.MeanWeight != null ).Any() == true
            ).FirstOrDefault();
}

public static bool HasNumbersData(int id)
{
    MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext ();
    return (from s in dc.Str_table 
            where s.sId == id 
            select s.AgeLengths
            .Where(a => a.Numbers  != null).Any() == true
           ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Thanks in advance
B

Comment: What types are `a.Numbers` and `a.MeanWeight`? You could possibly supply a `Func<T>` to return those as a method parameter.

Comment: a.Numbers is integer and a.MeanWeight is decimal

Comment: I'm not trying to be facetious, but your check for null will not work if the types are value types, which means you can ignore that check entirely in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Apologies, I didn't realise this was linq to sql. [Dennis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12579704/358221) appears to be on the mark.

Try injecting a `Func<T, TResult>` to inject the differing code:

```
public static bool HasData(int id, Func<AgeLength, object> selector)
{
    MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext ();
    return (from s in dc.Str_table 
            where s.sId == id 
            select s.AgeLengths
                .Where(a => selector(a) != null)
                .Any())
           .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And call like so:

```
HasData(1, a => a.Numbers);
HasData(1, a => a.MeanWeight);
```

If the `Numbers` and `MeanWeight` properties are in the same inheritance hierarchy, then you can substitute `object` with something more useful, but in this instance `object` is fine as you are just testing for null.

Comment: the code above throws the following exception: Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: The types are more precisely int? decimal?

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp: this is because you can't pass a predicate itself. See my answer below.

Comment: As @Dennis pointed out, you need an Expression, not just a Func since it seems to be DataContext related.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using some `DataContext`, you're using `IQueryable<T>`, and you're very limited with stuff you can write in your expressions. So, you need to pass an *expression* to your method, not a predicate itself:

```
static bool HasData(int id, Expression<Func<AgeLength, bool>> predicate)
{
    using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
    {
        return (from s in dc.Str_table
                where s.sId == id
                select s.AgeLengths
                .Any(predicate)
               ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Besides:

- there's `Any` overload, that accepts predicate expression;
- context must be disposed (see `using`);
- there's no need to write `someBoolExpression == true`; just write `someBoolExpression`.

Than you can call this method like this:

```
HasData(1, a => a.MeanWeight != null);
HasData(1, a => a => a.Numbers  != null);
```

Note, that the second argument is a lambda expression, not a method.
This is because of lazy nature of queries: you're providing a set of expressions, and the corresponding provider converts them into appropriate SQL.

Comment: Looks interesting, could you provide an example of how i could call this method? Expressions are still an esoteric subject to me...

Comment: while testing this from linqpad , i get the following erros: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<LINQPad.User.AgeLength,T>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<LINQPad.User.AgeLength,bool>>' any idea?

Comment: this was done by calling the method as follow HasData(4349,a=>a.Numbers!=null );  4349 is a valid id from my table

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp: I've updated the code after your first comment. There's no need to use `Expression<System.Func<AgeLength, T>>`, `Expression<System.Func<AgeLength, bool>>` will be enough. Hence, there's no need for `HasData` method to be a generic method.

Comment: still: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<LINQPad.User.AgeLength>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<LINQPad.User.AgeLength>'